# Why can't my user's iPod connect to our intranet server?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, wifi

I have an intranet server that is also a DNS server, that has its own IP set up as a Host (A) record with the name 'foo'.

I then have a wireless router hooked up, and a laptop, and an iPod.  The laptop connects and can go to 'foo' in a browser just fine.  The iPod connects and can hit the internet and the intranet server by IP address only--type in 'foo' and it never connects.

I tried manually editing the settings on the iPod so instead of the wireless router acting as a DNS server (it then just forwards DNS requests to the intranet server), it used the intranet server as a DNS server directly.  Besides not having to do that on the laptop, it didn't seem to have any effect.

How do I get it to connect?  My intranet app needs to be accessed by name in some places, so direct IP access won't cut it.

Comment: What DNS server software are you using?

Comment: The one built into Windows 2003.  Sorry, I should've specified that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure DNS is actually doing the resolution for your laptop? It could be resolving the name->IP via NetBIOS, which the iPod wouldn't support.

Check on a connected laptop "nslookup foo" and see what it comes back with, this should help you diagnose the problem. My guess is that the DNS server isn't actually resolving the IP, or DNS isn't forwarded properly.

Comment: You're right.  How do I get it to forward properly?

Comment: *** Can't find server name for address 192.168.0.1: Non-existent domain
*** Default servers are not available
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.1

Name:    foo.local.lan
Address:  10.0.10.100

Comment: Oh, I got it.  I just needed to enter the domain name into the router.  (It had said 'optional', and since I don't access foo.local.lan, but rather just http://foo, I didn't know I needed to do that.)

Comment: NetBIOS is teh debil.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably have a similar problem with any macs on your network.  Not totally familiar with iPod touch network settings, but in order for me to get the macs on our network to hit our intranet with just the name, i had to modify the "Search Domains" in the mac's Network Settings.

From your browser, try going to foo.domain.whatever (whatever the domain the DNS server is authoritative on).  If this works, add domain.whatever to the "Search Domains" field in the network settings on your iPod.

Oh, and be sure to try Dave's answer to make sure it's querying the right DNS server.  You said you had a wireless router, which may be using it's own DNS

Answer (score 0):

What wireless router are you using?

In my experience (and I've done specific research into this) whilst most routers have GUI settings for DNS settings, some don't then propagate those settings via DHCP to clients.

Check from another client (i.e. the laptop) which specific resolvers are being doled out via DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

If everything above seems to be ok and things still don't work, check out the domain suffix.
If it happens to be .local, then the problem is described here

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3389

I have added a new zone in my bind9 conf, a .lan one and all works ok